# Bash script: creating a variable based on part of a file name / part of a string using EXIF data from photo

Tags: bash, exif

I have a massive amount of photos I want to store in a folder structure that organises them by the genuine month and year they were taken.

Each photo has EXIF data that I have used to rename each file based on the date created:

```
identify -verbose $file | grep Original
```

Which might return something like this (white space included):

```
    exif-DateTimeOriginal- 2004-03-24 15-54-48
```

Next I want to create folders for the month and year in this string but cannot figure out how to do this.

So far my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'

cd ~/Pictures/all-pics

for file in *;
do
[ -e $file ] || continue
mv $file "$file.jpeg"
echo $file

file="identify -verbose $file | grep Original"

# the lines I need to create these variables go here 

mv $file /Documents/all-pics/$year/$month/

done
```

I'm sure there are a few ways to do this without even renaming the file but as I am new to shell scripting I haven't found any good documentation on how to set variables based on EXIF properties such as these.

I started off by trying to create these variables using methods such as the below but I am clutching at straws:

```
year="    exif-DateTimeOriginal- $year-??-?? ??-??-??"
month="    exif-DateTimeOriginal- ??-$month-?? ??-??-??"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### `exiftool` have extensible query options. It's based on Perl language.

Example:

```
exiftool -s3 "-DateTimeOriginal" -d "%Y %m" file.png
-------8<------------------
2023 01
```

Within a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file; do
    read year month < <(exiftool -s3 "-DateTimeOriginal" -d "%Y %m" "$file")
    dir=$year/$month
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    echo mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Remove the `echo` command when the output looks satisfactory.

##### Usage

```
./script <file(s)>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use bash regex to capture the `yyyy-mm` portion of the original date EXIF data and then use bash parameter expansion to extract the year and the month:

```
original_date=" exif-DateTimeOriginal- 2004-03-24 15-54-48"
printf "original date is $original_date\n"

if [[ "$original_date" =~ ([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}) ]] ; then 
    year_month="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" 
    year="${year_month%%-*}" 
    month="${year_month##*-}"

    printf "year is %s\nmonth is %s\n" "$year" "$month"
fi
```

Output:

```
original date is  exif-DateTimeOriginal- 2004-03-24 15-54-48
year is 2004
month is 03
```

The `$year` and `$month` variables can be used to build your path for creating the directories and moving the files.

Comment: I learned a lot from this, thank you! I need to dedicate some time to regex this year.